# Slide to answer is not working on HTC Wildfire S

Tags: lock-screens, calls, htc-wildfire-s

When trying to answer an incoming call, the slide up to answer never works! It moves, but doesn't actually pick up the call. Is there any way to change this??

Answer (score 1):

At android 2.3.3 you have to slide up/down the bar trying to move **out of the screen**.

[image: android 2.3.3]

---

If you update the phone to Android 2.3.5 given by HTC the lock screen changes to

[image: Android 2.3.5]

were you have to move the green/red phone in the down grey ring, which may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why should this happen, but I guess it is a problem with your dial-launcher. You can try some other apps with dialing function, and see if the problem still exists. I need further information to help you.:)